# how to get plain text from .xlsx using roo

Tags: ruby-on-rails, excel, roo-gem

When I open .xlsx files using `roo`, special characters in cells are converted to HTML tags.
ex)
hello **world**  -> \hello\**world\**\

how I can avoid this?
I want to get plain texts like "hello world".

When I open .xls files using `roo-xls`, special characters are converted to plain text as I expected.
ex)
hello **world** -> hello world

I open .xlsx files in this way.

```
Roo::Spreadsheet.open(path_to_file, extension: :xlsx)
```

.xls

```
Roo::Spreadsheet.open(path_to_file, extension: :xls)
```